# Location of roots in the Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Consider the polynomial:
\begin{equation}
P(z)=4z^4+2(1-i)z+1
\end{equation}
Suppose I wan't to study the zeros of this polynomial. I've thought about factoring it to:
\begin{equation}
P(z)=(z-z_0)^mG(z)
\end{equation}
In order to state that it actually does have a zero of order $m$ in $z_0$. I've not been able to factor it out, however. I don't really want to know the actual values of the zeros, but where they lie in the complex plane. Could that follow from the simple theorem that I tried to use?

This polynomial for sure does not look like it has simple zeros. Therefore, in order to see where these lie in the complex plane, there must be some indirect approach that I'm missing.

Summarizing, I wan't to know where it's possible zeros lie in the complex plane, and if that could follow from a simple theorem, or if it derives from a more tricky approach. If anyone can help, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Rouche's Theorem can be used to show that the roots lie in the unit disk $|z|<1$.

Comment: "Simple zeros" is a name used for zeros with multiplicity one. In that sense this polynomial has simple zeros.